# there is problem to install electron js successfully

Tags: javascript, electron

**i want to start my first project in electron js**
and my important files here:

**package.json :**

```
{
  "name": "electron-quick-start",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A minimal Electron application",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "keywords": [
    "Electron",
    "quick",
    "start",
    "tutorial",
    "demo"
  ],
  "author": "GitHub",
  "license": "CC0-1.0",
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

**main.js :**

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const path = require('path')

let mainWindow

function createWindow () {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      preload: path.join(__dirname, 'preload.js')
    }
  })

  mainWindow.loadFile('index.html')

  mainWindow.on('closed', function () {
    mainWindow = null
  })
}

app.on('ready', createWindow)


app.on('window-all-closed', function () {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') app.quit()
})

app.on('activate', function () {
  if (mainWindow === null) createWindow()
})
```

but i get this error :
**Electron failed to install correctly**, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again but my installation it remains on hold
i had deleted electron and try to reinstall that many times with this code:

> npm install --save-dev electron

but i can not solve this problem and when i want to start the project with

> npm start

again i get this problem :
*Electron failed to install correctly, please delete node_modules/electron and try installing again*

any body can help me?

Answer (score 1):

It's perhaps because you are behind a proxy. If this is the case, you can try to fix your problem so (change with your own proxy's IP address and port):

```
npm config set proxy http://192.168.1.11:8080
npm config set https-proxy http://192.168.1.11:8080
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Optionally check that your settings are saved:

```
npm config list
```

Add electron in your packages.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^8.2.5"
  }
```

Then try again:

```
npm install
```

If the electron package is correctly installed in your node_modules, but downloading the electron binary fails, run this (again customize the address of your proxy):

```
npx cross-env ELECTRON_GET_USE_PROXY=true GLOBAL_AGENT_HTTPS_PROXY=http://192.168.1.11:8080 node node_modules/electron/install
```

Cf. https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/20739#issuecomment-577981558.

Comment: The last sentence just did the trick. I set up the proxy. Everything worked well, but the last step: final GET on 'https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v8.5.5/electron-v8.5.5-win32-x64.zip'. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

"The best resolution is to try switching networks, or wait a bit and try installing again." Says official [docs](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/installation#troubleshooting)

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is an issue with https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start project electronjs major versions `^7.1.7` and `^8.0.3`.

It seems to infinitely stuck trying to do node install.js (from electron installed package)

```
> electron@6.0.0 postinstall /Users/XXX/XXX/electron-quick-start/node_modules/electron
> node install.js
```

The only major version that seems to work is v: `6.0.0`

```
  ...

  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "6.0.0"
  }

  ...
```

With version 6 it proceeds to download the actual electron zip:

```
Downloading tmp-2633-0-electron-v6.0.0-darwin-x64.zip
[======================================>      ] 88.0% of 63.21 MB (48.55 kB/s)
```

The issue is more likely with electron's download url compose logic and most likely not related to proxy.

The issue has already been logged in the repo. See also the issue log at https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start/issues/330#issuecomment-594242303